# Editing an html file in Node and Express (does something JQuery-esque exist for local files)?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a project for myself of building on an editor in Node (and Express) that would allow the user in the browser to edit an html page. I was wondering if there was a way to easily manipulate html files on the server in the same way one would manipulate the DOM using JQuery (or a package?).

Example:

**index.html**

```
...<div class="classA">some text</div>...
```

**app.js**

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result;

  //I would want something like
  result = data.find('classA').text('hello world'); // <-- psuedo-code 
  result = data.find('div').attr('something', 'aValue'); //<--- psuedo-code

  fs.writeFile(someFile, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

I imagine I could write regular expressions to find and edit an html page, I was wondering if however, an easier solution already exists. Any recommendations on ways to approach achieving my goal are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Comment: @robertklep - thanks, cheerio looks great